# Create entries using SQLite (Android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, junit, insert

I have problem with my insert method  while testing it by JUnit Android  Test and no enrty is saved in the database :

```
public long save(TAV t) {
    ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
    v.put(TAV_TITRE, t.getTitle());
    v.put(TAV_DATE, t.getDate());
    v.put(TAV_DESCRIPTION, t.getDescription());
    return db.insert(TAV_TABLE, null, v);
}
//this is the JUnit Test Method 
public void testAddition() {
    setUp();
    TAV t = new TAV("titre", "date", "decsritpion");
    m.open();
    m.save(t);
    Log.i(tag, "insertion");
    testShowAll();
}
```

HELP PLEASE !!!

Comment: Do you open an instance of the db?

Answer (score 0):

In your `save()` method, make sure you make an instance of your databse,something like `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();`.And remove `return` from `return db.insert(TAV_TABLE, null, v);` i.e use

```
public void save(TAV t) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
v.put(TAV_TITRE, t.getTitle());
v.put(TAV_DATE, t.getDate());
v.put(TAV_DESCRIPTION, t.getDescription());
db.insert(TAV_TABLE, null, v);
}
```

From the [SQLiteDatabase Documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

> public long insert (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values) Returns
>   the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

So if your purpose is just to add a row into your database then your method need not return anything.So you can just make return type of your method `void` and use `db.insert` inside.

Comment: It's a type long method ; it should have a return

Comment: That's why i changed it to `void`.Do you need to return the row ID of the newly inserted row?If not then you can just use as i mentioned.Check the edited answer.